# Global name not defined when function calls a function

Tags: python

I am able to run a script but when I attempt to call functions in it (that call functions in other files) from another module, I get a global name not defined error.

```
>>> reachable('192.168.1.200','192.168.1.1','test','password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "reachable.py", line 5, in reachable
    s1=reachableFrom.start_session(host1,user,pw,user,pw,'ssh')
  File "reachableFrom.py", line 21, in start_session
NameError: global name 'Secure_Shell' is not defined

# reachable.py
import Telnet, Session, Secure_Shell, re
from reachableFrom import start_session,send_commands_to_session
def reachable(host1,host2,user,pw):
    s1=reachableFrom.start_session(host1,user,pw,user,pw,'ssh')
    command='ping '+host2+' count 5'
    (success,results)=reachableFrom.send_commands_to_session(s1,command,conf_mode=False)
    out=re.compile(r'.* (\d*) percent .*',re.MULTILINE)
    m=out.match(str(results))
    return(m.group(1))
```

The start_session function works fine when I simply run reachableFrom.py from the command line.

```
#reachableFrom.py
import Session
import re
import Telnet
import Secure_Shell
import sys
method='ssh'
host1='192.168.1.200'
host2='192.168.1.1'
user='test'
pw='password'
def start_session(device, username, password, enable_username, enable_password, via):
    session1 = None
    if via == 'telnet':
        session1 = Telnet.Telnet(device, username, password, enable_username, enable_password)
    if via == 'ssh':
        session1 = Secure_Shell.Secure_Shell(device, username, password,enable_username, enable_password)
    return session1
def send_commands_to_session(session, command, conf_mode=False):
    ''' sends a series of cli lines to a device (seperated by ';') '''
    output = []
    # if command list comes in seperated by newline, replace with ';'
    command = command.replace('\n', ';')
    # split command list into individual lines
    commands = command.split(';')
    if session.login():
        if session.enter_enable_mode():
            session.page_skip()
            for line in commands:
                output=session.send_line(line)
            return (True, output)
    return (False, {})
s1=start_session(host1,user,pw,user,pw,method)
command='ping '+host2+' count 5'
(success,results)=send_commands_to_session(s1,command,conf_mode=False)
out=re.compile(r'.* (\d*) percent .*',re.MULTILINE)
m=out.match(str(results))
print(m.group(1))
```

`rick@ST2:~/python$ python reachableFrom.py
100`

So I am trying to figure out why calling Secure_Shell from reachableFrom.py works but not when initiated from reachable.reachable.  I figure it can be a problem with my understanding of the interpreter, namespace, or inheritance.  Thanks!

Comment: you could try to add an `if __name__=="__main__"` before your "`s1=start_session(host1,user,pw,user,pw,method)`" code, so you could import the module directly without this code being executed (it's the same code in your other module).

Comment: That did resolve the issue with the global name not being defined.   Further testing has shown me that I actually get different results from launching a script (e.g., test.py calls reachable.py which calls reachableFrom.start_session) from the shell versus calling it from the python interpreter.  The interpreter throws a global name error for reachableFrom when called via reachable.  

This is 75% an educational exercise.  Thanks for the tip!